# Why I can't delete the first file of FindFirstFile

Tags: visual-c++

Ido a windows service who delete all .tmp file of a directory. I use FindFirstFile function and do that :

```
BOOL cleanPath(){
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
DWORD dwError;

hFind = FindFirstFile(strcat(getDirectoryToClean(), "\\*.tmp"), &FindFileData);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    logError("Invalid file handle");
    return (-1);
}
else
{
    printf("first file %s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
    DeleteFile(strcat(strcat(getDirectoryToClean(), "\\"), FindFileData.cFileName));
    // List all the other files in the directory.
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
    {
        logInfo("deleting file");
        printf("  %s\n",FindFileData.cFileName);
        DeleteFile(strcat(strcat(getDirectoryToClean(), "\\"), FindFileData.cFileName));
    }
    dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);

    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        printf("FindNextFile error. Error is %u.\n", dwError);
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

}

The problem is the file on the FindNextFile loop are deleted with no problem but the first DeleteFile don't delete my first file found... I have no idea why, it's my first time with windows c development so maybe I missed something.

Comment: What´s the filename? ".."?

Comment: nope it's foo.tmp, I've lot of .tmp file on the directory, but only the first is not deleted

Comment: Check the return value of DeleteFile and of GetLastError

Comment: DeleteFile return 0 and GetLastError 2

Answer (score 0):

First file returned by FindFirstFile() API would be the current directory(.) which can not be deleted as it is not empty hence you are getting this error.

So you should check and if your file is not "." then only call DeleteFile()

Comment: you can check the FindFileData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY so that you would only delete the files from the directory.